# How can I SQL insert a record for every id in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've seen the insert select but I only want to get one value from the second table.  Here's what I'm thinking:

```
insert into table1
Values((select distinct id from table2),
"blah", "blah", "blah")
```

So after the Id, the rest of the values will be hard coded to whatever I want.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax does not use `values`:

```
insert into table1(col1, . . . )
    select distinct id, 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'
    from table2;
```

Notes:

- You should always use explicit column lists when using `insert`, unless you really, really know what you are doing.
- Use single quotes to delimit a string, not double quotes.

Comment: wow it's that easy, I feel bad

Comment: @Pittfall . . . Never feel bad when you learn something . . . at least if no one else gets hurt.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax looks like this:

```
insert into table1
select distinct id, 'blah', 'blah', 'blah' from table2
```

Use single quotes for string literals, like `'blah'`. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. if an object has an reserved word as name `"table"`.)